# Error while using aggregation with limit property on mongodb in asp.net MVC4.0?

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4

I use MongoDB and MVC 4.0.

The below code gave me an error, I tried many different ways but it always shows this error:

> "Command 'aggregate' failed: exception: A pipeline stage specification
>   object must contain exactly one field. (response: { "errmsg" :
>   "exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly
>   one field.", "code" : 16435, "ok" : 0.0 })"

My code:

```
 var matchSumcount2 = new BsonDocument 
                { 

                    { 
                        "$group", 
                        new BsonDocument 
                            { 
                                { "_id", new BsonDocument 
                                             { 
                                                 { 
                                                     "Device","$Device"
                                                 }                                                                                           

                                             } 
                                },
                                {
                                    "Clicks",new BsonDocument
                                    {
                                        {
                                            "$sum","$Clicks"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                "Day",new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    {
                                        "$sum",1
                                    }

                                }
                            }                   
                      } 
        },
        {
       "$limit",50
        }                             
        };
        var database = MongoDbManager.GetDatabase();
        var pipeline = new[] { matchSumcount2 };
        var list = database.GetCollection("rnd").Aggregate(pipeline);
```

I only want the first 50 records and then perform the aggregation.

What I am doing wrong here? Any suggestion or code sample to do this?

Comment: I can't see all your code, but it looks like you are attempting to encode all your pipeline stages into a single document. Rather, the aggregate command needs an array of documents. The $limit should be in it's own document not attached to the $project document.

Comment: if i remove $limit then this query run without any error why limit is not working with this?

Answer (score 0):

I made the comment above, but you didn't understand. I apologize for not being more clear. I'll use code examples to show you what is wrong.

You are doing this (effectively):

```
{ 
  { $group: { _id: { Device: "$Device" } } },
  { $limit: 50 }
}
```

But that is wrong. $group and $limit should not be siblings in a document. They should be elements in an array.

```
[ 
  { $group: { _id: { Device: "$Device" } } },
  { $limit: 50 }
]
```

Like I mentioned in the comment, I cannot see the start of your code, so I can only make an assumtpion based on the end. Your first line is probably a new BsonDocument(). That is wrong. It should be new BsonArray();

```
var pipeline = new BsonArray();
pipeline.Add(new BsonDocument(
{
  { "$group", new BsonDocument { { "_id", new BsonDocument { { "Device", "$Device" } } } } }
});

pipeline.Add(new BsonDocument("$limit", 50));
```

Comment: it will not work. i have created two table in mongodb 1st contains 67 records and 2nd contains 50 records if i execute the same query as you said on both table then the result is different how?.

Comment: 2 tables with different documents are going to get different results. You need to be more specific in the differences. Also note that there is no sorting in here, so the order things come out will be different.